# While loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
let age = "";

while (age !== NaN) {

  age = prompt("what is your age");

  Number(age);

}
```

I can not leave the while loop although I write a number in the prompt box, why?

Comment: You initialize `age` to a  string, and the return value from `prompt()` is also always a string, and no string is ever `===` to `NaN`.  The call to `Number(age)` has no effect; you probably want `age = Number(age);`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function to determine whether a value is *NaN* or not. You have to add `age == ""` as part of the condition with `||` to pass for the initial value (empty string).

The condition should be:

```
while (isNaN(age) || age == "")
```

You also have to re-assign the converted value to the variable.

```js
let age = "";
while (isNaN(age) || age === "") {
  age = prompt("what is your age");
  if(age == null)
    break;
  else
   age = Number(age);
}
```

Comment: let age = "";

while (isNaN(age) || age == "") {

  age = prompt("what is your age");

  age = Number(age);

} 

is a good solution. But whats is wrong with age === "" (with 3 equal signs). I leave the loop when I click Cancel or OK without writing.

let age = "";

while (isNaN(age) || age === "") {

  age = prompt("what is your age");

  age = Number(age);

}

Comment: @H.A.A, when *cancel* button is clicked *age* has null value, in that case you have to *break* the loop.....updated the answer....please check.

Comment: I got it. age = Number(age); changes the type of age to Number that is why age==="" does not work because empty "" is not a number.

Comment: The following code solved my problem:

let age = "";

while (isNaN(age) || age == "") {

    age = prompt("what is your age");

    age = Number(age);

}

let age = "";

while (isNaN(age) || age === "") {

  age = prompt("what is your age");

  if(age == null)

    break;

  else

   age = Number(age);

}

leaves tho loop without asking the age again.

Comment: @H.A.A, does my answer solve your question or you want some thing else?

Comment: @H.A.A, then you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green......thanks